# Error when trying to enable trace in Playwright python POM in conftest.py

Tags: automated-tests, trace, playwright-python

I'm a VERY new to Playwright and am trying to enable the trace. I am trying to follow the documentation but am receiving an error:

ERROR             [100%]
test setup failed
page =

```
@pytest.fixture()
def set_up_tear_down(page) -> None:
```

> ```
>   browser = chromium.launch()
> ```

E       NameError: name 'chromium' is not defined

conftest.py:7: NameError

Process finished with exit code 1

Any assistance would be appreciated.

conftest.py

```
import pytest
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


@pytest.fixture()
def set_up_tear_down(page) -> None:
    browser = chromium.launch()
    context = browser.new_context()
    # Start tracing before creating / navigating a page.
    page.set_viewport_size({"width": 1536, "height": 800})
    page.goto("google.com")
    # Stop tracing and export it into a zip archive.
    context.tracing.stop(path="trace.zip")
    yield page
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `E NameError: name 'chromium' is not defined` because you don't have the `playwright` fixture in the `set_up_tear_down(page)` fixture.

Just add it like below and you won't get that error:

```py
import pytest
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


@pytest.fixture()
def set_up_tear_down(playwright, page) -> None:
    chromium = playwright.chromium
    browser = chromium.launch()
    context = browser.new_context()
    # Start tracing before creating / navigating a page.
    page.set_viewport_size({"width": 1536, "height": 800})
    page.goto("google.com")
    # Stop tracing and export it into a zip archive.
    context.tracing.stop(path="trace.zip")
    yield page
```

Please have a look at the documentation for [pytest fixtures](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/test-runners#fixtures) and [the Browser class](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-browser) for more information.